# HTML Canvas clears in a circular fashion, and won't clear entirely?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So, I draw my circle:

```
var homeimg = document.createElement("img");
homeimg.src = "img/nav/home-inactive.png";
var homec = document.getElementById("home-canvas");
var homectx = homec.getContext("2d");
homectx.beginPath();
homectx.arc(85, 85, 85, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
homectx.closePath();
homectx.shadowColor = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)";
homectx.shadowOffsetX = 2;
homectx.shadowOffsetY = 2;
homectx.shadowBlur = 3;
homectx.drawImage(homeimg, 0, 0, 170, 170);
homectx.beginPath();
homectx.arc(0, 0, 85, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
homectx.clip();
homectx.closePath();
homectx.restore();
```

We get this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JldP.png

Dope. Now I want to clear the Canvas--wipe it completely clean.

```
homectx.clearRect(0, 0, homec.width, homec.height);
```

This takes a circular chunk out of the top left corner: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRHHV.png

Okay, no big deal. homec's width and height are both 180px (and have never changed), so I'll just bump it up if we're clearing in a circle shape from 0, 0--that should work.

```
homectx.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 600);
```

Same sized chunk vanishes.

What am I doing wrong here? How do I clear this?

Comment: What's the goal here ? The first path declaration is not used, you're restoring an unsaved state, and your clipping is made on the second arc (which center is at 0,0) And I won't talk about misused closePath, everybody does this...

Answer (score 0):

@apemom,
 You code `homectx.clip()` is the culprit here. To better understand what i am referring to, please read this documentation on how canvas.clip() works.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_clip.asp

Quote:
The clip() method clips a region of any shape and size from the original canvas.

***Tip: Once a region is clipped, all future drawing will be limited to the clipped region (no access to other regions on the canvas). You can however save the current canvas region using the save() method before using the clip() method, and restore it (with the restore() method) any time in the future.***

Good luck!